# NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element (aka Any) has no subscript members

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, predicate

after updating xcode to 8 version, I got this error
[image]

```
searchArray = allArray.filter({$0["test"] as? String == findCode
        let resultText: NSString = ($0["test"] as? String)
        return (resultText.range(of: searchText, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive).location) != NSNotFound
}) as NSArray!
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please also post your code as text in your question.

Comment: Already, thanks! @rmaddy

Comment: The problem is that the compiler has no idea what the type of `allArray` is. And neither do I, for that matter. If you want help, show the relevant declarations. What _is_ this thing? What is `allArray` and where did it come from?

Comment: @matt 
Declaration: 
var allArray : NSArray!
Next in viewDidLoad: 
teamAllArray = NSArray()
And then: 
if let data = results["data"] as? NSArray  {
      teamAllArray = NSArray()
      teamAllArray = data
}

Comment: Okay, but what is this an array _of_? Swift needs to know that. (And so do I.) You see, the whole source of your problem is that you keep using these Objective-C classes. _This is Swift. Use Swift types._ You should be using a _Swift_ array here. Then everything would just work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ultimate source of your problem is this line:

```
var allArray : NSArray!
```

NSArray is an Objective-C class. You are trying to write Objective-C code in Swift. Don't. This is *Swift*. Use *Swift* types! Write *Swift* code!

This is presumably an array *of* something. Swift needs to know what that is. For example, if this is an array of dictionaries, than its type would be `[[AnyHashable:Any]]`. If you use Swift types, your code will just work, because Swift will know what the elements of your arrays are.

Comment: Thanks, it helped, but what I should do in case
var dict = allArray.object(at: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row) as? NSDictionary

Error: Value of type [[AnyHashable:Any]] has no member 'object'

Comment: Just use subscripting. You are still writing ObjectiveC code. Write Swift code! Really.